# Forced not to fast in Ramadan?

Tags: sawm

I am a boy of 15 years of age. Now, my parents don't allow me to fast everyday during Ramadan because they say that it will be tough for me and hard for me to fast everyday. So, they allow me to only fast some days but not all in Ramadan. Now, my question is, Will I be punished for this? Is it my fault, and then what do I have to do to repent? Will I have fast extra in future once I am not forced not to? And if it still mandatory for me to fast but I am unable to go against them or their decision?

Comment: What will happen if you disobey them and refuse to break your fast?

Answer (score 3):

Fasting Ramadan is mandatory in Islam. It is one of the five pillars of Islam.

[image]

If you are of age, you need to fast, refusal of the parents is not an excuse. The prophet PBUH said:

> لا طاعة لمخلوق في معصية الخالق [دواوين السنة المشهورة]
>
> Do not listen to the creation to sin the creator.

However, if this was an optional fasting (not in Ramadan) it would have been a different story (regardless of how old you are). Since obeying the parents is obligatory and sunnah salah/fasting is not, they can request that from you. [[Fatwa Ben Baz #18637‏]](http://www.al-eman.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8/%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%89%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%86%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%85%D8%A9%20%D9%84%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%AD%D9%88%D8%AB%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%A9%20%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A1%20%C2%AB%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AC%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B9%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%B9%D8%A9%C2%BB%20***/%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%85%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D9%81%D9%84%20%D8%A8%D8%AF%D9%88%D9%86%20%D8%B1%D8%B6%D8%A7%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%86/i328&d261310&c&p1)

Comment: But what if I am unable to go against them and thus can't fast?

Answer (score 3):

Your parents are saying not to fast because they love you, they think your body won't be able to stand the fasting and it can harm you. So you need to convince them that you are now grown up and can fast without any problem.  You can tell your parents that you will eat and drink well in suhoor (pre-dawn meal) so that you can stand the fasting.

I assume you don't have any health problems, if that is case, Quran itself says that those who are ill should fast later when they are well.

Answer (score 0):

You must be aware that is one of mandatory act in Islam we are not allowed to obey our parents, orders in the mandatory's acts although Islam so emphasizes in respecting the parents. As a result you are not allowed to leave your fasting and it would be sin for you not to do it completely. Then I suggest you try to justify them about that in order to keeping the respect and doing the wajibs (mandatory acts).

Answer (score 0):

Given that fasting in Ramadhan is mandatory for all able-bodied adults (and I'm assuming you are one, at age 15), it is compulsory to disobey them and make sure not to miss any fasts unless you are traveling or ill. However, if they force-feed you, then you are free of sin and can simply make up for the missed fasts after Ramadhan without any need for guilt. Please bear in mind that regardless of what they do or say, you are not allowed to abuse them or be disrespectful in any way. Disobeying parents in mandatory (fardh) issues can and must be done with utmost respect to them. It is also extremely important to state explicitly that by forcing you to skip a mandatory act of worship, they are accruing sin and hence the displeasure of Allah Subhanahu wa Ta'ala and His beloved Nabi (peace be upon him and his progeny).

Answer (score -2):

I think u must tell them the following incident.
"Once HOLY PROPHET (BPUH) asked his SAHABA what is your favourite ibadat in Islam they answered politely that WE like the FAST OF RAMZAN IN SO MUCH SUMMER"
I HOPE THAT WILL BE ENOUGH FOR YOUR PARENTS.
U KNOW YOUR PARENTS LOVE YOU THA'S WHY THEY SAID LIKE THIS. BUT REMEMBER ALLAH LOVES YOU 70 TIMES MUCH AS COMPARED TO YOUR PARENTS.
SO TELL THEM ALL THESE THINGS BY FOLLOWING THE AAPECT OF HONOUR AND THEIR DIGNITY.